# Expo / React Native: ellipsizeMode and number TextInput?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

i'am triyng to set a TextInput o expo with the following code, but it's not working:

```
<TextInput
      numberOfLines = { 5 } 
      ellipsizeMode = 'clip'>
</TextInput>
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this with the propierty 'multiline = {true}'

like this:

```
<TextInput
  multiline = {true}
  numberOfLines = { 5 } 
  ellipsizeMode = 'clip'>
```